# Lightroom 3 doesn't recognize my iPhone 3GS

Tags: macos, iphone

I have Lightroom 3.6, and an iPhone 3GS. When I plug my iPhone in via USB port it shows up in iPhoto, but not in Lightroom. Lightroom does recognize my Lumix camera though... what's up?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure to install the latest update online or offline on your Lightroom to update profiles related to cameras in Lightroom Engine, and secondly, your iPhone camera may have used Lumix's hardware when it introduced its profile to Lightroom.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the profiles. Camera RAW profiles are used to process images, not to recognize USB hardware or import photos.

Comment: OK, if you connect another iPhone to the USB port, it shows the same unrelated profile in Lightroom?

Comment: I don't know why profiles are relevant to the question? If the phone does not even show up…

Comment: Im sorry for poor english type . Because my language is not english .   As I am translating with Google Translator and inserting words automatically somewhere, I mean, does it mean if I'm wrong with other iPhone phones as well? Or in a particular model